# Is there a way to identify if my Cassandra node is using GC or G1?

Tags: cassandra, garbage-collection

I'm running Cassandra DSE and I would like to know if there is a command or configuration file where I can identify if the node is using GC or G1? I took a look on cassandra.yaml and cassandra-env.sh but wasn't able to find it.

Thanks

Comment: G1 or CMS would be more correct. Both are types of garbage collection (GC).

Answer (score 2):

cassandra-env.sh will tell you, or more recently the jvm.options. check for `-XX:+UseG1GC` option. If the node is running you can do a `ps -ef | grep UseG1GC` to check for jvms running with it enabled.